# is it possible to use both materializecss and material in angular 4?

Tags: angular, material-design, materialize, angular-material2

I was using material angular with my angular 4 project but it has very less features so I've also install  materializecss into my same project. For normal UI it's working fine but any javascript action like dropdown is not working and I'm not getting any error in crome console.

So just just wanted to know is it because of I'm using  both angular's material and materialize in my angular 4 project ?

Comment: Why not use only materializecss?

Comment: I've already done development using angular material and for some new feature I wanted to use materializecss.